# Draw a beam for a mechanical calculation

Tags: tikz-pgf

In my LaTeX document, I need a graphic of a beam to calculate the unknown forces and so on...

Now, I create something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=3pt] (0,0) -- (8,0);
    \draw[->,line width=2pt,red] (4,0) -- (4,-1.5) node [below] {$F=mg$};
    \draw[->,line width=2pt,red] (0,0) -- (0,1.5) node [above]{$F_A$};
    \draw[->,line width=2pt,red] (8,0) -- (8,1.5) node [above]{$F_B$};
    \draw[->,line width=1pt,green] (8.2,0) -- (9.7,0) node [above]{x};
    \draw[->,line width=1pt,green] (0,-0.2) -- (0,-1.7) node [below] {z};
    \node (l) at (2,0) [above,blue] {$\frac{l}{2}$};
    \node (l2) at (6,0) [above,blue] {$\frac{l}{2}$};
    \draw [fill,green](0,0)circle[radius=0.5mm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I think it can be better :-)

Thank you...

BTW: It is an I-beam (DIN EN 10024)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your figure looks pretty good already. How can one improve it? There are many things which one may want to do, here are three of them:

1. Make the arrow heads nicer.
2. Define styles for recurring things.
3. Use relative positioning along paths.

This list can be extended, of course.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,force/.style={->,line width=2pt,red}, %<- define styles
displacement/.style={->,line width=1pt,green!70!black}]
    \draw[line width=3pt] (0,0) -- (8,0);
    \draw[force] (4,0) -- ++ (0,-1.5) node [below] {$F=mg$};
    \draw[force] (0,0) -- ++ (0,1.5) node [above]{$F_A$};
    \draw[force] (8,0) -- ++ (0,1.5) node [above]{$F_B$};
    \draw[displacement] (8.2,0) -- (9.7,0) node [above]{x};
    \draw[displacement] (0,-0.2) -- (0,-1.7) node [below] {z};
    \path (0,0) -- (8,0) node[pos=0.25] (l) [above,blue] {$\frac{\ell}{2}$}
    node[pos=0.75] (l2) at (6,0) [above,blue] {$\frac{\ell}{2}$};
    \draw [fill,green!70!black](0,0)circle[radius=0.5mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]