# A beam with forces

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used the code found in the answer of this similar question [Draw a beam for a mechanical calculation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490752/draw-a-beam-for-a-mechanical-calculation)
modified accordingly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,force/.style={->,line width=2pt,red}, %<- define styles
displacement/.style={->,line width=1pt,green!70!black}]
    \draw[line width=3pt] (0,0) -- (10,0);
    \draw[force] (6,0) -- ++ (0,-1.5) node [below] {$F=mg$};
\draw[force] (0,0) -- ++ (0,1.5) node [above]{$F_A$};
\draw[force] (5,0) -- ++ (0,1.5) node [above]{$F_C$};
\draw[force] (10,0) -- ++ (0,1.5) node [above]{$F_B$};
    \draw[displacement] (10.2,0) -- (11.7,0) node [above]{x};
    \draw[displacement] (0,-0.2) -- (0,-1.7) node [below] {y};
    \path (0,0) -- (10,0) node[pos=0.25] (l) [above,blue] {$\frac{\ell}{2}$}
    node[pos=0.55] (l2) at (6,0) [below,blue] {$\frac{\ell}{5}$};
%      node[pos=1] (l3) at (10,2) [above,blue] {$\frac{4\ell}{5}$};
    \draw [fill,green!70!black](0,0)circle[radius=0.5mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I add the arrows and lines as well as the text as shown in the following image? Thanks a lot for any kind of help.
[image]

Comment: Your code already contains arrows, lines and text. Please show some effort to do it yourself, and explain what is causing you problems.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I apologize. The forces and the axes are there. I want just to add the arrows that highlight the different distances. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new nodes slightly above or below the given coordinate. For example,

```
\draw (0,0) node[above=3mm, inner sep=0, outer sep=0](A1){} -- (0,1.5);
```

will place an empty node called `A1` at a spot 3mm above `(0,0)`. I created a style called `spot` so I can reuse the style. There are also new styles for the label arrows and their labels, all of which I added to a `tikzset` in the preamble, but you can add the styles to your `tikzpicture` if you prefer.

Then you can draw the label arrows from node to node using the code

```
\draw[<->, labelarrow] (A1)--node[mylabel] {$\frac{\ell}{2}$}(A2);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{mylabel/.style={fill=white, text=blue, inner sep=1pt},
    labelarrow/.style={red, very thick},
    spot/.style={above=#1, inner sep=0, outer sep=0},
    spot/.default={3mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,force/.style={->,line width=2pt,red}, %<- define styles
displacement/.style={->,line width=1pt,green!70!black}]
    \draw[line width=3pt] (0,0) -- (10,0);
    \draw[force, shorten <=-6mm] (6,0)node[spot](A3){}node[spot=-3.5mm](A6){} -- ++ (0,-1.5) node [below] {$F=mg$};
\draw[force] (0,0)node[spot](A1){} -- ++ (0,1.5) node [above]{$F_A$};
\draw[force, shorten <=-5mm] (5,0)node[spot](A2){}node[spot=-3.5mm](A5){} -- ++ (0,1.5) node [above]{$F_C$};
\draw[<->, labelarrow] (A1)--node[mylabel] {$\frac{\ell}{2}$}(A2);
\draw[<-, labelarrow] (A5)--++(-.5,0);
\draw[<-, labelarrow] (A6)--++(.5,0);
\path (A5)--node[mylabel] {$\frac{\ell}{5}$}(A6);
\draw[force] (10,0)node[spot](A4){} -- ++ (0,1.5) node [above]{$F_B$};
\draw[<->, labelarrow] (A3)--node[mylabel] {$\frac{4\ell}{5}$}(A4);
    \draw[displacement] (10.2,0) -- (11.7,0) node [above]{x};
    \draw[displacement] (0,-0.2) -- (0,-1.7) node [below] {y};
    \draw [fill,green!70!black](0,0)circle[radius=0.5mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```